# how to replace lemma in corpus obtained from wordnet in R

Tags: r, text-analysis, lemmatization

I used wordnet library in R and able to get lemma for corpus, below is code which I have used.

```
library(tm)

doc1 <- "Stray cats are running all over the place. I see 10 a day!"
doc2 <- "Cats are killers. They kill billions of animals a year."
doc3 <- "The best food in Columbus, OH is   the North Market."
doc4 <- "Brand A is the best tasting cat food around. Your cat will love it."
doc5 <- "Buy Brand C cat food for your cat. Brand C makes healthy and happy cats."
doc6 <- "The Arnold Classic came to town this weekend. It reminds us to be healthy."
doc7 <- "I have nothing to say. In summary, I have told you nothing."


doc.list <- list(doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5, doc6, doc7)

N.docs <- length(doc.list)
names(doc.list) <- paste0("doc", c(1:N.docs))

query <- "Healthy cat food"

my.docs <- VectorSource(c(doc.list, query))
my.docs$Names <- c(names(doc.list), "query")

my.corpus <- Corpus(my.docs)
my.corpus

my.corpus <-tm_map(my.corpus,content_transformer(tolower))

#remove potentially problematic symbols
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) { return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",x)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "/")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "-")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ":")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ";")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "@")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "\\(" )
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ")")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, ",")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, toSpace, "_")
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, content_transformer(removeSpecialChars))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removePunctuation)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stripWhitespace)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeNumbers)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeWords, c("status","please","need","mail",
                                              "email","unable","re","fw","st","th","sep","nov","thank","kmmvlkm","prb"))

#Stem document
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus,stemDocument)

library(wordnet)
setDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
initDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
lapply(my.corpus,function(x){
  sapply(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),"[[:space:]]+")), function(word) {
    x.filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", word, TRUE)
    terms    <- getIndexTerms("NOUN",1,x.filter)
    if(!is.null(terms)) sapply(terms,getLemma)
  })
})
```

Now I want to replace words in corpus with lemma received post using wordnet library, Can any please share if anyone knows how to get the solution, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   **Output** <- lapply(my.corpus,function(x){
   sapply(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),"[[:space:]]+")), function(word) {
        x.filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", word, TRUE)
        terms    <- getIndexTerms("NOUN",1,x.filter)
        if(!is.null(terms)) sapply(terms,getLemma)
      })
    })
```

Output should be a list. Convert that list into corpus

```
    cprs <- as.VCorpus(Output)
```

and then convert crps into dtm. I hope it helps